# Update CMakeLists QT4 to QT5

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I was using an old `CMakeLists` of a package based on QT4:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)
project(pol)

add_compile_options(-std=c++17)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS qt_build roscpp sensor_msgs cv_bridge image_transport)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_package()

rosbuild_prepare_qt4(QtCore QtGui) # Add the appropriate components to the component list here


file(GLOB QT_FORMS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ui/*.ui)
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/pol/*.hpp)

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})


file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS src/*.cpp)


add_executable(pol ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})
target_link_libraries(pol ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS pol RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

Now I'm trying to move to recent version of QT5, so I started like that:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

project(pol)

add_compile_options(-std=c++17)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS qt_build roscpp sensor_msgs cv_bridge image_transport)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_package()
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)

rosbuild_prepare_qt4(QtCore QtGui) # Add the appropriate components to the component list here

file(GLOB QT_FORMS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ui/*.ui)
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/fmf_qt/*.hpp)

QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT5_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})

include_directories(
    ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS src/*.cpp)

add_executable(pol ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})
target_link_libraries(pol Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS pol RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

Now I'm getting errors that I believe are due to my new `CMakeLists` such as

```
error: incomplete type ‘QImage’ used in nested name specifier
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class QImage’
```

The package is developed under `ROS ubuntu 18.04 LTS` and compiled with `gcc 8.1` Do you know what's wrong with my new `CMakeLists`?
The package was working with my old `CMakeLists`!

**EDIT**:

I run `cmake` correctly:

```
cmake ../src -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=../devel
```

But I get the errors when I run `make`

Comment: Where do those errors come from -- when you run `cmake` or when you invoke `make` on the generated makefiles?

Comment: @G.M. when I run `make` I edited my post

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want code to be **included into the question post itself**, not *linked*. Please, fix that issue in your question.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried that but it was saying that there is too much code

Comment: Hm, strange. Both code snippets has less then 60 lines in total. But what is more vital, the error is in your `.cpp` code, not in the `CMakeLists.txt`. (That is, `CMakeLists.txt` could be bagged, but `.cpp` is bugged too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting these errors because the source file being compiled at the time is making use of `QImage` but the compiler can only see a forward declaration rather than the complete class definition.

For the source file(s) in question you need to add (assuming your include paths are correct)...

```
#include <QImage>
```

Previously, when using `Qt4` the `QImage` header was probably being included transitively by one of the other `Qt` header files which is why there was no error.

Answer (score 3):

This is how use Qt with cmake:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

    project(QCameraBug)

    # required packages
    find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick Multimedia REQUIRED)

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp" "main.qrc")

    target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_14)

    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        Qt5::Core
        Qt5::Quick
        Qt5::Multimedia
    )
```

This works perfectly for me. Hope this is helpful